# mkdir: cannot create directory '/opt/bitnami/grafana/data/plugins': Permission denied with nfs folder

Tags: kubernetes-helm, grafana, nfs

After I installed Grafana in my Kubernetes cluster using helm charts, the pod is showing logs like this:

```
grafana 13:47:48.44 
grafana 13:47:48.46 Welcome to the Bitnami grafana container
grafana 13:47:48.50 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
grafana 13:47:48.51 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues
grafana 13:47:48.52 
mkdir: cannot create directory '/opt/bitnami/grafana/data/plugins': Permission denied
grafana 13:50:37.28 
grafana 13:50:37.28 Welcome to the Bitnami grafana container
grafana 13:50:37.28 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
grafana 13:50:37.28 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues
grafana 13:50:37.29 
mkdir: cannot create directory '/opt/bitnami/grafana/data/plugins': Permission denied
```

This is the NFS folder permission, what minimal permission should I change to make it runnable of the pod?

```
[root@k8smasterone reddwarf-monitor]# pwd
/data/k8s/reddwarf-monitor
[root@k8smasterone reddwarf-monitor]# ll
total 1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 15 21:35 grafana
```